# My simple circular buffer doesn't work correctly

Tags: c#, circular-buffer

I'm trying to implement simple circular buffer.

```
class MyCircularBuffer
{
    byte[] Buffer = null;

    private Object BufferLock = new object();

    int readIndex = 0;
    int writeIndex = 0;

    int SpaceBetweenIndexes
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    int ReadIndex
    {
        get
        {
            return readIndex;
        }
        set
        {
            readIndex = value;
            CalculateSpaceBetweenIndexes();
        }
    }

    void CalculateSpaceBetweenIndexes()
    {
        if (readIndex <= writeIndex)
        {
            SpaceBetweenIndexes = writeIndex - readIndex;
        }
        else
        {
            SpaceBetweenIndexes = Length - (readIndex - writeIndex);
        }
    }

    int WriteIndex
    {
        get
        {
            return writeIndex;
        }
        set
        {
            writeIndex = value;
            CalculateSpaceBetweenIndexes();
        }
    }

    int Length;

    int Count
    {
        get
        {
            lock(BufferLock)
            {
                return Buffer.Count();
            }
        }
    }

    public MyCircularBuffer(int length)
    {
        Buffer = new byte[length];
        this.Length = length;
        ReadIndex = 0;
        WriteIndex = 0;
    }

    public byte ReadByte()
    {
        while (SpaceBetweenIndexes <= 1)
        {
            CalculateSpaceBetweenIndexes();
        }

        ReadIndex++;

        if (ReadIndex < Length)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Read from index " + (ReadIndex-1) + " value " + this[ReadIndex - 1]);
            return this[ReadIndex - 1];
        }
        else
        {
            ReadIndex = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Read from index " + (Length-1) + " value " + this[Length-1]);
            return this[Length-1];
        }
    }

    public void WriteByte(byte value)
    {
        WriteIndex++;
        
        if (WriteIndex < Length)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wrote from index " + (WriteIndex-1) + " value " + value);
            this[WriteIndex - 1] = value;
        }
            
        else if(writeIndex == Length)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wrote from index " + (WriteIndex-1) + " value " + value);
            this[WriteIndex-1] = value;

            WriteIndex = 0;
        }
    }

    public byte this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            lock(BufferLock)
            {
                return Buffer[index];
            }  
        }
        set
        {
            lock(BufferLock)
            {
                Buffer[index] = value;
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Code to generate the test:

```
class Program
{


    public static  MyCircularBuffer buff = new MyCircularBuffer(10);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        

        System.Threading.Thread t1 = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(DrawByte));
        System.Threading.Thread t2 = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(WriteByte));

       
        t2.Start();

        t1.Start();


        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void DrawByte()
    {
        Random rand = new Random(50);

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            buff.WriteByte((byte)(rand.Next()+1));
        }
    }

    public static void WriteByte()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            buff.ReadByte(); //In this example my class is showing the results, so I didn't write here Console.Writeline...
        }
    }
}
```

First thread will use method ReadByte for getting bytes from this buffer and second thread will use method WriteByte for writing bytes to the buffer.
I have writeindex and readindex which are moving on the buffer. Everything seems to works good but this:

[image: a bug]

Any ideas/advices? Hope you can help me, guys!

Comment: Perhaps you should add the code to generate the test case as well, such that people answering the question can test their solution.

Comment: You should add locking around `readByte()` and `writeByte()` methods

Comment: What should happen when a reader will lag behind writer or vice versa? Should they wait for each other?

Comment: @AntonGogolev writer always should be above but not more than one "lap", reader should wait for new data if it's in as the same position as writer

Comment: @CommuSoft ok, I'm adding that to the post

Comment: Your locks are too narrow - you're only locking on the buffer operations, yet other variables with state are changing outside of the locks. Try locking on every method and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: @Dominik why? I have lock on get and set buffer. It's not enough?

Comment: @Terrykk - You need to lock on all state, not just the buffer.

Comment: Should it be the same lock or i need to create another one?

Comment: @Terrykk To avoid race conditions. Consider the case where you have 2 threads, both want to write. First threads does `WriteIndex++`, then the scheduler moves on to the next thread, which also does `WriteIndex++`. Then both threads write. So now borth threads write to the same position and you have invalid data.

Comment: @Dominik ok, i know that, but i have only one thread to write and one to read. It's good advice from you, but I guess it's not a solution for my problem

Comment: @Terrykk probably not, but nonetheless, have you tried it?

Comment: yeah, i tried and it didn't help me, but thanks. @yue shi noticed that i don't have condition to make writer wait for reader and I'm trying to solve that

Comment: @Terrykk there is no such thing as "**simple** circular buffer" which also is thread safe and implements producer-consumer pattern. Rather than wasting your time, better look at `System.Collections.Concurrent` and pick something that best suits your needs.

Answer (score -1):

Wish I had enough "Reputation" to put this to comment. Anyway, why would you think there is a problem? Inside the red box you highlighted, wasn't the reader thread just waiting? Once it got a chance to run it picked the index 8, which was the right value.

Comment: Is it the problem, because reader skipped one whole lap.
For example writer wrote 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 in buffer with length 5,
so reader read 1,2,3,4,5 , 11 (so skipped 6,7,8,9,10)

Comment: What makes writer to wait for reader? Writer could keep writing to the circular buffer, when reader got a chance to run it just picks up the value at ReadIndex. In this case is 0, the value at index 0 is 11. Am I missing something?

Comment: oh, It's stupid but I don't have nothing to make writer wait for reader. Conditions which I wrote are not enough for that, thanks. I'll try to do something with that